# Facebook deleted post share count not updated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I will share particular page on my facebook, shared successfully, Here after get the share count via http://graph.facebook.com/www.domain.com/test.html

```
result:
{
   "id": "http://graph.facebook.com/www.domain.com/test.html",
   "shares": 1
}
```

After some time I have deleted my post, Recheck the above url the share count not updated ?
I need the result below

```
{
   "id": "http://graph.facebook.com/www.domain.com/test.html",
   "shares": 0
}
```

Is this possible for programmatically like php,Json,Xml

Comment: sorry @Josef, but we can't modify facebook's source code :) I think we can't modify the result of a call to facebook API

Comment: What u tell about this query?any possible?

Comment: nothing to do at all, @Josef, we can't get inside facebook's servers and change how they "do things", so what you want to do (modify the call's results) can't be achived